# How to Authenticate mobile app user with UniqueID using Firebase or AWS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-authentication, amazon-cognito

I have a mobile app which will only use a Unique Code for users to login. How can i authenticate using Firebase or AWS Cognito or any other cloud providers? The screen looks like below :

[samplescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2fRg.png)

Should i end up writing a custom Authentication WebService for this and will Apple iTunesConnect review and approve my app without a username, pwd and email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the first question:

> How can i authenticate using Firebase or AWS Cognito or any other
>   cloud providers?

According to your request, I think it's more of a login "passcode" than traditional authentication. So user should get this code from the app developer. If that's the case, then simply insert some data into the Firebase and call the query for the passcode entered on the client side.

The second one:
Check the App Store Review: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

> Make sure your app has been tested on-device for bugs and stability
>   before you submit it, and include demo account info (and turn on your
>   back-end service!) if your app includes a login.

I think apple doesn't take the authentication as a necessary step(After all the are tons of tool-apps out there on the app store without any account involved, I personally even have 2 apps on the app store without authentication :p ). But in order to let them test your app, you need to provide the passcode(even with detailed explanation on how to use the passcode if necessary)

Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much @code-farmer. My app binary got rejected saying... Enter demo credentials in the "User name" and "Password" fields
- Once you've completed all changes, click the "Save" button at the top of the Version Information page. Should i just enter a sample Unique code in the textfield that says username? and password as empty?

Comment: @riderforest Since your case is not the common way doing log-in with both user name and password(at least the way Apple assumes). I think by providing your passcode and some explanations inside of the "Notes" text field describing how to use your passcode will be enough. If you tap the question mark next to "Notes" you see :"Additional information about your app that can help during the review process. Include information that may be needed to test your app, such as app-specific settings."

Comment: Thanks @CodeFarmer will do that.